# Ubuntu how to run ng commnd

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

In Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed nodejs with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

To confirm, I used the command `which nodejs` and it returns

> /usr/bin/nodejs

I want to run an Angular project. I have also created 'node_modules' folder and updated the 'Angular CLI'. However, the `ng` command is not working in terminal.

### **Edited**

Below is my package.json content:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

The Blank terminal is given in below screen:

[image]

I see after running the command `npm install -g @angular/cli` the below error comes:

> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib' npm
>   ERR!     at Error (native) npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, access '/usr/local/lib'] npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!
>   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/local/lib' } npm ERR!  npm ERR! Please try running this command
>   again as root/Administrator.

EDITED 2

---

Now I see after placing ng serve command:

> niladri@niladrib:/var/www/html/ngAngular$ ng serve
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:17
>       constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
>                                                              ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:3:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)

Comment: check your node version by node -v. Also, how did you install angular-cli. Following https://github.com/angular/angular-cli ?

Comment: It shows v4.2.6 . I installed angular cli as npm install -g @angular/cli.

Comment: @Shivi - Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Shivi I want to run this https://github.com/shakyl333/Laravel-5.5-Angular-4-demo/tree/master/ngAngular

Comment: U need to update your node to above 6.9, which is the minimum requirement for angular cli to run... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites

Comment: @Shivi Thanks Shivi. But which command need I run to get this?

Comment: @Shivi I run these command : curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs but always stored node 4.

Comment: u can follow the steps in the accepted answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Comment: @Shivi - can you please post your latest reply (https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version) as your answer so that I marked as Correct? You deserve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-cli has certain prerequisites, which includes node version > 6.9, as can be seen here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites

To update node to latest version, we can follow :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Answer (score 1):

You need to install AngularCLI globally in order to serve up the application using `ng serve`.

To do this run the following command in your terminal:
`npm install -g @angular/cli` (use sudo if you need administrator privileges on Ubuntu.)

This will install AngularCLI globally. Which you can then simply used to serve the application by navigating to the folder and typing `ng s`.

Comment: Actually I see that my nodejs version is 4. How can I upgrade this to at least 6.9 as Shivi suggested above?

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara This should update node and npm for you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Comment: I have updated my question. can you please suggest further.

Comment: You need to run is as the superuser. `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` I'll update my answer.

Comment: I ran the command sudo npm install -g @angular/cli ; But when I run nodejs -v, it still shows 4.2.6 ; Any idea?

Comment: The ng serve runs but have some errors. I have updated my question (under Edited 2)

Comment: Do you have the latest version of node installed? If so, try running npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

check the json package file, look at the script section, write the text after start in your terminal. example in that same file you can see the installed dependencies in the folder node_modules

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please check and explain what command I need to write in the terminal? Kindly explain it by edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

ok, first write to your terminal ng --version, with this you will get the version of angular cli that you have installed on your desktop and compare it with this "@ angular / cli": "^ 1.6.7" if the version of your angular cli at the bottom, update it, the how to do it is in the documentation, after that write in the terminal sudo npm install, so that all the dependencies of the Json package file are installed after running ng serve

Comment: I go to the folder where my project is located like /var/www/html/ngAngular/ and write this command ng --version, it shows a blank terminal

Comment: I have edited my question and added a screen shot for your help.

Comment: Actually I want to run this Angular project - https://github.com/shakyl333/Laravel-5.5-Angular-4-demo/tree/master/ngAngular

Comment: the solution I sent you as an answer is below

Answer (score 0):

hey @Shivi first install npm install -g sass node-sass. this in a global way.  then enter the ngAngular folder in install the dependencies with "npm install" and this will be enough after ng serve to run the project. an image that if it runs 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOTaL.png)